# git commit: Show untracked files on top

Tags: git

If I forget to `git add` a file, and then run `git commit .`, then I see message like this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch provision-device
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/provision-device'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   main.go
#   modified:   pkg/foo/bar.go
#   modified:   pkg/foo/baz.go
#   modified:   pkg/foo/blue.go
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   ...

# Untracked files:
#   missing.go
```

If there are many modified files, then it is likely, that I don't notice the untracked file.

I usualy don't have untracked files.

Is there a way to configure git to show the untracked file on top?

Then it is less likely that I forget a file.

Comment: If no option exists, one could create a wrapper that parses the output.

Comment: I would recommend using some terminal extensions that help you with that, e.g. [`Oh My Posh`](https://ohmyposh.dev/) can provide Git status within the current prompt

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, beside a custom prompt, is to add a [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) which would deny the commit if there is any untracked files:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check for untracked files
untracked_files=$(git ls-files --exclude-standard --others)

# If there are untracked files, deny the commit
if [ -n "$untracked_files" ]; then
  echo "Aborting commit due to untracked files:"
  echo "$untracked_files"
  exit 1
fi

# If there are no untracked files, allow the commit
exit 0
```

That way, you would have to add or stash those files, before being able to complete the `git commit`.

Answer (score 1):

The `pre-commit` hook suggested by VonC is definitely a good way to go.

To answer your question more directly: there also is a [`prepare-commit-msg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) hook, which precisely allows you to edit the file which contains the starting message before opening a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution using [pre-commit.com](//pre-commit.com):

```
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: no-untracked-files-in-git
        name: no-untracked-files-in-git
        language: system
        entry: "bash -c 'files=$(git ls-files --exclude-standard --others); echo $files; test -z \"$files\"'"
```

I know that the question was different, but this pre-commit-hook solves my issue.

Comment: So basically the same pre-commit hook idea than the one I suggested?

Comment: @VonC yes, I have "stolen" the git command from your solution (thank you for that) , except that mine uses pre-commit.com.

Comment: Looks good to me. pre-commit.com can be handy!